# lifting of control data along a stratified morphism

Tags: singularity-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a stratified map between Whitney stratified spaces such that for each stratum $S$ of $Y$, $f:f^{-1}(S)\to S$ is a proper stratified submersion. Let $\mathscr{T}_Y$ be a Thom-Mather control data of $Y$. Is there a Thom-Mather control data $\mathscr{T}_X$ on $X$ which is compatible with $\mathscr{T}_Y$ and $f$?

P.S. If Y has only one stratum, this is a theorem of Mather which is used to prove Thom's first isotropy lemma.